# SQL Sever import wizard (2014) doesn't display Excel

Tags: sql-server, sql-import-wizard

I want to import an Excel table into my database but in the import wizard list I don't see Excel as a datasource. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the ODBC driver is missing - check in Control Panel. If it's missing, try re-installing the driver from office setup.

As a work around, you may also save the excel spreadsheet into csv and import the csv as a plain text file data source.